# expression engine upload file types

Tags: ee2, file-uploads, file-manager

At the moment I can only set this to 'all file types' or 'images only' but would like to specify a small list (.doc, .docx, .pdf) for some documents, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to do what you want. It's either "images" or "all".

If one does not already exist then creating a custom fieldtype that would only permit uploads of a particular type should be possible. Start with the existing file fieldtype and see if you can modify it to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can determinate the allowed file type in EE from this file ./system/expressionengine/config/mimes.php

and be sure that Admin -> Security and Session Preferences, "Apply XSS Filtering to uploaded files?" set  to "yes".

and this will apply to all member groups except Superadmin, superadmin members always can upload all files type.

Comment: thanks but I cannot alter the list or control the upload which is really what I am after

Comment: I don't understand what you really want , but If you ask if you can control the mimes type directly from CMS , so you can't. the only way is by editing the mimes.php file.